# Sublime text 3 Build System in C++ which takes input from Terminal

Tags: c++, c++14, sublimetext3

I was looking for a sublime text 3 build system which could run my program in C++14, takes input from user using terminal and show my output also in terminal. After some search in online i find such a build system online which does that. The build System is as follows :

```
{
/* Custom Build file for C++14, supports input from user.
* Default terminal emulator is gnome-terminal. You can change it to xterm or
* terminator by changing "gnome-terminal -x" in "cmd" in "variants" field to
* "xterm -e" or "terminator -x".
*/
"cmd": ["g++", "-std=c++14", "$file", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++, source.cxx, source.cpp",
"variants":
[
{
"name": "Run",
"cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ -std=c++14 '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && gnome-terminal -x bash -c '\"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" ; read'"]
}
]
}
```

It runs my code perfectly and does everything what I was looking at. But I got an message on sublime console which wrote :

```
# Option "-x" is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
# Use "-- " to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
[Finished in 1.3s]
```

What does that mean ? How can i fix that by editing my above sublime build ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning message is perfectly self-explanatory. In the "Run" section, the command is

```json
"cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ -std=c++14 '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && gnome-terminal -x bash -c '\"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" ; read'"]
```

After the `&&`, instead of having `gnome-terminal -x bash -c ...`, simply put `gnome-terminal -- bash -c ...` and you'll be all set.

Comment: I accepted your answer. And yes i will upvote once i reach 15 reputation. Thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

On your Sublime Text window...

1. Cmd + Shift + P
2. Type Install Package
3. Wait for 1s - 2s & type "Terminus"
4. After Terminus is installed, create a new sublime build with this [json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuk6/cpp/master/best_cpp_macos_build.sublime-build)

```js
{
  "target": "terminus_exec",
  "cancel": "terminus_cancel_build",
  "focus": true,
  "cmd": ["g++", "-std=c++14", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
  "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
  "working_dir": "${file_path}",
  "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

  "variants": [{
    "name": "Run",
    "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ -std=c++14 '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
  }]
}
```