# How to setup cpp build file for sublime text?

Tags: c++, installation, build, sublimetext

I am trying to setup up sublime text for competitive programming. I want to pass input from some file say "inputf.in" and get the output in some file say "outputf.txt".

Comment: So you don't want to do the file reading and writing explicitly in your programs, but you want the editor to *redirect* (hint hint) input and output to and from your program? What computer-science courses have you done that doesn't teach you about input/output redirection?

Comment: I like how you’re trying to act knowledgeable. You probably dont do competitive programming where every second counts, these little configuration saves enough time to rank up in a coding contest.

Comment: For MacOS, I found this quite interactive https://stackoverflow.com/a/77523655/8108725

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution online, but it was for windows. I made a few changes to make it work for ubuntu.

1. Open Sublime Text editor and then go to Tools > Build System > New
   Build System.
2. Paste the following code in the file and save it.
3. Name the file as “CP.sublime-build“.

For windows

```
{
"cmd": ["g++.exe", "-std=c++17", "${file}",
        "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe",
        "&&", "${file_base_name}.exe<inputf.in>outputf.out"],
"shell":true,
"working_dir":"$file_path",
"selector":"source.cpp"
}
```

For ubuntu

```
{
"cmd": ["g++ -std=c++17 ${file} -o ${file_base_name} && ./${file_base_name} < inputf.in > outputf.txt"],
"shell":true,
"working_dir":"$file_path",
"selector":"source.cpp"
}
```